# How can I make a grid class that conserves memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Most of the time, the way you would make a grid of objects in C++ is like this:

```
class Grid {
private:
    GridObject[5][5];
};
```

But is there a way to save memory and not use tiles that have nothing in them? Say you had a chess board. What if you didn't want to use memory in unoccupied spaces? I was thinking of ways to do this but they are inefficient.

Comment: The best approach really depends on the charateristics of the data in your grid (lots of adjacent cells with same value, only few unique values, but random pattern in grid, specific pattern in grid,...). Can you give more info? Also, what's the size of GridObject?

Answer (score 2):

I would have a structure like:

```
class GridObjectWithIndex
{
public:
    size_t index;
    GridObject obj;
};
```

Where index is a value of the form `x + y * GRIDSIZE` so that you easily can decode the `x` and `y` of it.

And in your `Grid` class have:

```
class Grid
{
    std::vector<GridObjectWithIndex> grid_elements;
};
```

Comment: Maybe I could order them by index too to speed it up. This is kind of what I thought of but I didn't know if it would be fast enough

Answer (score 0):

The first thing which comes to my mind is storing pointers GridObject* in the grid. It will still consume sizeof(GridObject*) bytes for non-existent elements but it saves you from the nightmare of managing the data structure. If it's not absolutely critical - don't make it more complex than needed. It's definitely not worth for chess (8x8).

fritzone's solution will be good if you have a small number of elements over a wide range of indices. However think about read/write performance.

If you want to save the space while sending over the network or saving in a file you may want to consider archiving algorithms. Althogh it only makes sense for large sets on data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling for is called a *sparse* data-structure, the most striking examples being *sparse matrices*.

The idea is to trade memory for CPU: use less memory at the cost of more operations. In general it means:

- having a structure only representing the "unusual" values (with a fast access by coordinates)
- keeping the "usual" value aside

As a proof of concept, you can use a `std::map< std::pair<size_t, size_t>, Object >` for the sparse structure and just have another `Object` on the side for whenever it's not present in the `map`.